# Getting error ets jan 8 2013,rst cause:4,boot mode(1,6) wdt reset

Tags: esp8266, code-review

I'm working on a project to send ultrasonic sensor data to my webserver. For that I'm using ESP8266  WiFi module, 3.3V regulator IC by giving input volt of 5v from aduino uno.

I successfully uploaded a code but in serial monitor I got an error

```
ets jan 8 2013,rst cause:4,boot mode(1,6) wdt reset.
```

Please, tell what does it mean?

Here is my code. Guide me if I made something wrong. Thanks in  advance.

**Note:**
Before sending sensor values I successfully send a raw data  manually to webserver, i.e string data, but when I try to send sensor values, I got an error.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "VENTURE 11";
const char* pass = "12345678";

WiFiClient clientx;
const int trigPin = 8;  //Digital port D5
const int echoPin = 9;  //Digital port D6

long duration;
float distance;
float Mdistance;
float MAX_HEIGHT = 0;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);                                  //Serial connection
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  WiFi.begin("VENTURE 11", "12345678");   //WiFi connection
  Serial.println("Setup iniated");
  while (WiFi.status() != 3) {  //Wait for the WiFI connection completion
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
    Serial.print("WIFI STATUS : ");
    Serial.println(String(WiFi.status()));
  }
  Serial.println(String(WiFi.status()));
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(String(WiFi.status()));
  if (WiFi.status() != 3)
  {
    WiFi.begin("VENTURE", "12345678");   //WiFi connection
    while (WiFi.status() != 3)
    {
      Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

    // Calculating the distance
    distance = (duration * 0.034) / 2;


    if (MAX_HEIGHT == 0) {
      //MAX_HEIGHT = distance;
      Serial.print("Max height has been set to ");
      //Serial.print(distance);
      Serial.println(" cm");
      Serial.println("Waiting for 5 seconds...");
      delay(5000);
    } else {
      Serial.print("Distance:\n");
      Serial.print(distance);
      Serial.print("cm\n");
      Serial.print("Distance:\n");
      Serial.print(distance / 100);
      Serial.print("m\n");
      delay(1000);


    }

    HTTPClient http;
    String Data = "x=" + (String)distance + "&y=" + (String)MAX_HEIGHT + "&z=0";
    //String Data = "x=Finally&y=Did&z=it;)";
    http.begin("http://testingblahblah.000webhostapp.com/IOTCON.php");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    int sent = http.POST(Data);
    Serial.println(sent);
    String httpPayload = http.getString();
    Serial.println(httpPayload);
    if (sent > 0)
    {
      Serial.println("Message has been sent");
    } else {
      Serial.println("unable to send data");
    }
    delay(20000);

  }
}`
```

Comment: Do you see the serial prints on your serial monitor? where do they stop?

Comment: also in String Data, you should type String(distance) and String(MAX_HEIGHT) (paranthesis around the argument not the func)

Comment: Please check SSID name of the WiFi in the code.

Comment: port D6 doesn't exist on most of esp8266 board, change it to another pin

Comment: @Erez.Electronic.can, D6 is a label and constant on NodeMcu and Wemos boards and is mapped to io 12. but you are right about wrong pin. **io 6 to io 10 are used for communication with the flash memory**

Answer (score 3):

Found a possible solution.
I was facing with the same problem.
Apparently this is a hardware stack overflow watch dog preventing malfunction. This may not apply to every possible scenario but I discovered that the allocated pin number on the board itself is incorrect.
What is numbered 03 is in fact D15 for example. So assigning the pin to D15 worked but 3 created this error.
I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2):

Your `loop()`:

```
void loop() {
  Serial.println(String(WiFi.status()));
  if (WiFi.status() != 3)
  {
    WiFi.begin("VENTURE", "12345678");   //WiFi connection
    while (WiFi.status() != 3)
    {
      Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    // Other code...
  }
}
```

While waiting for the connection, you are creating `String` objects at a very high rate, since your `delay(20000)` is in the `else` clause.

This means you are possibly running out of memory, as you are creating the `String` objects with every iteration, which is in the Megahertz range.

You likely don't need the `String(...)` wrappers, as the `Serial.println()` function can work with C-style strings returned by the `WiFi` library. Then, your program won't be allocating memory to hold the result of `WiFi.status()` millions of times per second, which you don't use later on in your program.

Comment: the answer is not valid anymore. begin with const char* parameters exists. but this answer was never the right answer