# ets Jan 8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,7)

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am facing a issue with the ESP8266-01 as the following below:

chksum 0x42
csum 0x42
~ld
ets Jan 8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,0)
wdt reset

Anyone has the solution please help!!

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>  //Load liquid Crystal Library
LiquidCrystal LCD(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);  //Create Liquid Crystal Object called LCD
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "your-ssid";
const char* password = "your-password";
const char* host = "your-localhost";

#define in 7
#define out 8
#define trigPin 10
#define echoPin 13
#define relay 2
#define led 6            //red color
#define led2 A0           //yellow color
#define led3 9           //green color

int count = 0;

int distanceCm;
long duration;

void IN()
{
    count++;
    LCD.clear();
    LCD.print("Number of Item:");
    LCD.setCursor(0,1);
    LCD.print(count);
    delay(10);
    LCD.setCursor(3,1);
    LCD.print(distanceCm);
    delay(10);
    LCD.setCursor(6,1);
    LCD.print(" cm");
    if(distanceCm <= 3){
     delayMicroseconds(10);
     LCD.setCursor(10,1);
     LCD.print("Full");
     digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }

  if(distanceCm > 3 && distanceCm <= 5){
     delayMicroseconds(10);
     LCD.setCursor(10,1);
     LCD.print("Enable");
     digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  } else{
    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  }

  if(distanceCm > 5){
     delayMicroseconds(10);
     LCD.setCursor(10,1);
     LCD.print("Empty");
     digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
}

void OUT()
{
  count--;
  LCD.clear();
  LCD.print("Number of Item:");
  LCD.setCursor(0,1);
  LCD.print(count);
  delay(10);
  LCD.setCursor(3,1);
  LCD.print(distanceCm);
  LCD.setCursor(6,1);
  LCD.print(" cm");
   if(distanceCm <= 3){
     delayMicroseconds(10);
     LCD.setCursor(10,1);
     LCD.print("Full");
     digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }

  if(distanceCm > 3 && distanceCm <= 5){
     delayMicroseconds(10);
     LCD.setCursor(10,1);
     LCD.print("Enable");
     digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  } else{
    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  }

  if(distanceCm > 5){
     delayMicroseconds(10);
     LCD.setCursor(10,1);
     LCD.print("Empty");
     digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);

  LCD.begin(16,2);
  LCD.print("Item Counter");
  delay(2000);

  pinMode(in, INPUT);
  pinMode(out, INPUT);
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);

  LCD.clear();
  LCD.print("Item In Box:");
  LCD.setCursor(0,1);
  LCD.print(count);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
     // ESP.wdtFeed();
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

 // ESP.restart();
}

int value = 0;

void loop() {

 delay(0);
 delay(5000);
  ++value;

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(50);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distanceCm = duration * 0.034/2;

//******************************************************//
//IR Sensor Counting Object
  if(digitalRead(in))
  IN();
  if(digitalRead(out))
  OUT();

  if(count<=0)
  {
    LCD.clear();
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
    LCD.clear();
    LCD.print("No Item in box");
    LCD.setCursor(0,1);
    LCD.print("box is empty");
    delay(200);
  }
   else{
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
   }

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 8095;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    WiFi.begin(ssid,password);
    while (WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
      delay(0);
    }
  }

  String IRCount, myDistance;
  IRCount = String(count);
  myDistance = String(distanceCm);
  // We now create a URI for the request
  String url = "/Registration/write_data.php";
  url += "?item=";
  url += IRCount;
  url += "&distance=";
  url += myDistance;

  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  int timeout = millis() + 5000;
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (timeout - millis() < 0) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
  delay(0);
}
```

Comment: it is a watchdog reset. what is flashed in the esp8266?

Comment: @Juraj Flash Size: 1M(512K SPIFFS) flash Node: DIO

Comment: i tried all the flash size already but the error still there

Comment: that is not what I asked

Comment: Sorry... i don't understand what you mean flashed in the esp8266

Comment: GPIO 0  pins that i using it in the esp8266-01

Comment: what firmware or sketch is flashed? it is a software error the reset, so tell us what did you upload

Comment: I not sure what is the error going on... but i use the WiFiClient example to upload the dummy data to the php localhost webpage and it works but when i use the below following text file to upload the data to the webpage and it shows the above error [ESP8266_upload.txt](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/files/2660837/ESP8266_upload.txt)

Answer (score 1):

esp-01 has 4 io pins: RX, TX, io 0 and io 2. other pins are not accessible. io 6 to io 11 are wired to on-board flash memory and can't be used.

what are you thinking by using other pins then 0 and 2? how did you wire those sensors and leds to esp-01?

Comment: Because for the sensors and leds... I want pass the sensors data to my server. So is it possible to save my sensor data into the MySQL database and display it on my webpage.   I wired those wires on the Arduino UNO board

Comment: Do you have any ideas to pass the sensor data to the PHP localhost server webpage? or is it required to change another wifi receiver to pass the data to my localhost webpage?

Comment: My issue is the same as this forum before https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48234/getting-error-ets-jan-8-2013-rst-cause4-boot-mode1-6-wdt-reset But i don't see any solution for this

Comment: there is no magic that would read Uno pins in connected esp8266. you could use Firmata with Firmata Master esp8266 library but simpler is to write two sketches

Comment: but the other sketches connect to the main sketches?

Comment: the problem you linked is different. there is no Uno. sensors are wired to esp8266 dev board

Comment: i no write the esp8266 connection in the source code... i just write the sensors that connect to the UNO board... i not sure that is correct or not

Comment: you need sketch in Uno and sketch or firmware in esp8266

Comment: you mean that i need to create two sketch which is uno boards code and the esp01 source code? Sorry... i totally no idea how to do it

Comment: step by step. first create and debug a sketch for Uno without networking with output to Serial Monitor.

Comment: or buy an esp8266 dev board like Wemos/Lolin or NodeMcu and attach the sensors to it.